# Constructors, destructors and pointers (and vectors and arrays and delete and that)

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, destructor

Funky title, but honestly I couldn't think of anyone better, sorry :(

While experimenting with pointers I came across this and I need help understanding it. Basically, I create a vector of a pointer to an object.  When deleting the pointer that's in the vector, I expect the original ovject to be deleted as well. They are one and the same no?

Here's what I think I do in the code that follows I create a dynamically allocated array, I then put the pointer to half of the elements of the array in a vector of pointers. Each step of the way every object of the class testDestructor knows which 'order' it was created in, they all get assigned an incrementing number via a static integer.

I then pop_back and delete all the pointers in the vector. I only use pop_back because I wanted to see if they get deleted by the vector class, apperantly they don't, but idk if I'm missing something there. The important bit is I delete it.

Now, what I expect to happen is that this deletes the corresponding elements of the array as well. This is what SHOULD happen, because the vector and the array element point to the same place in the memory. ie, the destructor should get called.

So when I then delete the array, I expect that either only 5 of the elements get deleted, or a run-time error occurs (I've had this happen before when I try deleting pointers that already are deleted, but that might have been a different scenario idk). Namely, I expect that only the destructor should only be called five times.

HOWEVER, that's not what happens. The constructor gets called 10 times but the destructor gets called 15 times. What am I missing? Am I missing a constructor (I only know about default constructors and copy constructors, are there more), or is it something else? Because, in my mind, when the destructor is gone the object is gone.

Sorry if it's too much code:

testDestructor.h:

```
#ifndef TESTDESTRUCTOR_H
#define TESTDESTRUCTOR_H

class testDestructor
{
public:
   testDestructor();
   testDestructor(const testDestructor &);
   ~testDestructor();

   static int maxTest;
   int test;
};

#endif
```

testDestructor.cpp:

```
#include "testDestructor.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int testDestructor::maxTest = 0;

testDestructor::testDestructor()
{
   test = maxTest++;
   cout << "testDestructor nr " << test << " created successfully\n";
}

testDestructor::testDestructor(const testDestructor &destructorToCopy)
{
   test = maxTest++;
   cout<< "testDestructor nr " << test << " created successfully (using the copy constructor\n";
}
testDestructor::~testDestructor()
{
  //maxTest--;
   cout << "testDestructor " << test << " destroyed successfully\n";
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testDestructor.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "   creating pointer array:\n\n";
   testDestructor *testPtr = new testDestructor[10];

   cout << "   intitiating vector\n\n";
   vector<testDestructor*> testVct;


   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {

      cout << "   pushing back vector " << i << ":\n";
      testVct.push_back(testPtr + i);
      cout << "testDestructor " << testVct[i]->test << " pushed back\n";
   }
   cout << "\n";

   for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      cout << "   popping back vector " << i << ":\n";
      cout << "testDestructor " << testVct[i]->test << " popped back\n";

      delete testVct[i];
      testVct.pop_back();

   }
   cout << "\n";

   cout << "   deleting pointer array\n\n";
   delete [] testPtr;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, would you care to shorten the question, now that we have a hint for the reason of the behavior? That's the only way others would benefit.

Comment: Rule of thumb: exactly one `delete` for each `new`, exactly one `delete[]` for each `new[]`. You have: one `new[]`, one `delete[]`, and five `delete`s.

Comment: I don't know how to shorten the question tbh. I acctually wanted to (and I do realise it's a lot), but I don't really know how, sorry.

Comment: @PutBoy: Just like you would write a bug report: 1. Brief description of the problem, 2. Minimal setup (the code is fine, but there's no need to split it into three files; also it could be shortened by, say, inlining the methods), 3. Observed and expected behavior, 4. What have you done to understand the problem, your thoughts, etc.. You might want to shift the code to the very bottom. *Brevity is a virtue*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When deleting the pointer that's in the vector, I expect the original
>   ovject to be deleted as well. They are one and the same no?

No, they're not the same, and your terminology "deleting the pointer" implies you need to go and re-read some basic stuff about pointers in C++.

`new` creates things, and returns a pointer to what it creates. `delete` destroys things and is passed a pointer to the thing to destroy. The pointer is unchanged - it just doesn't point anywhere useful following a delete.

What you're trying to do is `delete` individual objects in an array of objects created with `new[]`. That simply cannot be done. You can only delete the whole lot with delete[]. If you want to have individually deleteable objects, use a `std::vector<TestDestructor>`.

Comment: ...but this might require a copy or even a move constructor.

Comment: True - but not in the simple example class given ;-)

Comment: Note the careful use of *might* in my comment ;-)

Comment: I don't think I need to re-read so much as read ;P There's a reason why I wrote this code, I wanted to understand the new and delete key word. I checked the adresses of the different pointers after posting this, and no they don't point to the same adress, which you state. I still don't understand why though.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the first five instances of `testDestructor` are deleted twice: Once by `delete testVct[i]` and another time by `delete [] testPtr;`.

**The first `delete` is wrong.**

The objects are *owned* by `testVct` and thus their destruction may be carried out only through `delete[]`ion of `testVct`. You can `delete` individual objects only if they are allocated by `new`.

Comment: This is incorrect. You can delete an object through any pointer that points to it. It is up to the programmer to ensure that the object is deleted only once.

Comment: @Code-Guru You can destroy an object through any pointer, but you may only delete memory that was allocated.

Comment: Ahh...testVct is a vector of pointers, but pointer testPtr points to an array of objects. *That* certainly makes a huge difference since none of the objects are allocated with new. I guess I should look more closely at the code before opening my mouth.

Answer (score 1):

operator `delete[]` will call the destructors of the items in the array before it deletes the array itself. If you wish to delete some of the items in the array manually you need to set its array index value to `NULL` afterwards. Calling the destructor twice on the same object is undefined behaviour and will hopefully end badly for you.

Comment: There is no way to remove a class-type object from an array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's look at your variable declarations:

```
testDestructor *testPtr = new testDestructor[10];
vector<testDestructor*> testVct;
```

This says that testPtr is a pointer to an object of type testDestructor and testVct is a vector of pointers to objects of type testDestructor.

In addition, you allocate an array of testDestructor objects with the new operator and assign the address of the first element in testPtr. Now testPtr can be used as an array to testDestructor **objects**.

Note that you have not allocated memory for any individual testDestructor objects. This means that you delete any pointers to the objects in the array will result in undefined behavior. On the other hand, using delete[] on testPtr to deallocate the array is permissible.

The general rule here is that every delete or delete[] must have a matching new or new[] and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

First

In my test, this program will core dump at 'delete testVct[i];'

My g++ version is 4.1.6

Maybe you can init testPtr:

```
testDestructor *testPtr[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    testPtr[i] = new testDestructor;
```

Second

you delete a pointer twice
1) delete testVct[i];
2) delete [] testPtr;